# Service Account Name was not generated

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've created several GAE applications but failed to retrieve "Service Account Name" - there is no gserviceaccount mail on a 'Application Settings' page. My goal is to add service accounts of those applications to a list of members of the main application with edit permissions.
I've tried to add account to a list of members of main project just by following pattern <appId>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com but it failed with following error "The email account you invited is not a valid Google account".
My second idea was to create service account member on non-main project first following same pattern it didn't lead to an error but it has a following status "Invitation sent. Waiting for response".
Have no idea how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate any help.
Just for your notice: main application has billing enabled and has generated service account. Non-main applications have default version deployed and marked as "running".

Answer (score 0):

Services account are always created by default when you create a new project in the Google Cloud Platform.

So there's no need for you to add them or re-create them in your project.

You may find them in the Permissions page under the main project section in the [Developers' Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Or by using the URL https://console.developers.google.com/project/**YOUR_PROJECT_NAME**/permissions and using your real project name.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Problem is the it wasn't generated by default. Under permissions page I only see my email and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Older apps/projects didn't create service accounts.

Add the service account by

1. Going to **https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/permissions**
2. Press **Add Member**
3. Add this email **YOUR_PROJECT_NAME@appspot.gserviceaccount.com**